# Pacotes python com instalação de dependencia

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber se assim como em pacotes .deb por exemplo, é possível em meu `setup.py` eu configurar as dependências para meu pacote, e ao executar:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

As mesmas serem instaladas automaticamente. Ja pesquisei internet afora mas tudo que encontrei acabou me deixando confuso, coisas como "requires", "install_requires" e "requirements.txt".

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu `setup.py` decerto está a usar uma função `setup()` dos `settuptools`.
Deve incluir nessa função o argumento `install_requires` com a lista das dependências.

Por exemplo:

```
setup(
    name='exemplo',
    install_requires=[
        'babel >= 1.0',
        'pytz',
    ],
)
```

Esclarecendo o `requirements.txt`: é frequentemente usado com `pip` para indicar uma lista de pacotes a instalar, em vez de usar essa lista diretamente no `pip`. Não está relacionado com o `setup.py`, mas acaba por ter uma função semelhante ao ìnstall_requires`, daí poder gerar confusão.

Answer (score 0):

Suponho que você irá escrever um pacote no padrão PyPI (para uso com o [pip](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html), por exemplo, ou [easy_install](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#installing-easy-install)), [aqui há um exemplo completo de como fazer isso](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/dependencies.html).